# <jQuery> What is equivalent of canPlayType() in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to figure out the jQuery equivalent of

```
document.getElementById("myVid").canPlayType("video/mp4")
```

Comment: Why? Is it not working in plain JavaScript? Why do you feel it would be better to wrap the DOM node with jQuery when the function/method itself is expecting to be chained to a DOM node?

Comment: Actually it's because I'm already keeping the video as a jQuery object in the global context, and I already have all the event triggers set up using jQuery to do an AJAX pull of JSON to figure out which video to load next.  Last step is figuring out which extension would be supported.

Answer (score 1):

Try `$('#myVid').get(0).canPlayType("video/mp4")`.

Using `get` will give you access to the DOM object. See [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/get/).

Comment: Why? What does it do? (And yes: *I* know what it does, but I'm willing to bet that the OP doesn't, given the question; explanation helps the OP - and others in future - learn something useful from the answer which makes it a better answer).

Comment: I tend to agree with David's question. Just because you can use jQuery doesn't mean you should.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I never actually thought about how jQuery interacts with the DOM... though since you mention it, it makes sense that jQuery is an abstraction that communicates with the JavaScript, and the JavaScript accesses the DOM.  Thanks for the documentation, Amir!